# Бот не создает таблицу с пользователями

Tags: python, discord.py, sqlite3

Вот код:

````
import os
import discord
import asyncio
import random
import sqlite3
os.chdir(r'c:\Users\qq891\Documents')
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle
from asyncio import sleep
from discord.utils import get

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')
bot.remove_command('help')

connection = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        name TEXT,
        id INT,
        cash BIGINT,
        rep INT,
        lvl INT
    )""")
    connection.commit()

    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.member:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 100, 1, 0)")
                connection.commit()
            else:
                pass

connection.commit()

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 100, 1, 0)")
    else:
        pass

@bot.command()
async def баланс(ctx):
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""Хеей, В кармане у **{ctx.author}** **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]} :moneybag:**"""
        ))


@bot.event
async def on_ready(self):
    print('Хела здесь  {0}!'.format(self.user))

bot.run("токен")```

Бот подключился к server.db все вроде нормально, но при использование команды >баланс в консоле ошибка что бот не видит таблицу с названием users
````

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить:

```
for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.member:
```

На:

```
for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
```